# File bug for iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How exactly filling bugs for the iPhone SDK with Apple works?

I've always seen people mentioning we should fill bugs and duplicates is their way of measuring priority, but it's not clear to me:

1. How to actually fill the bug;
2. How to flag someone else's bug as a duplicate, and;
3. What do I need to tell people I've filled that bug and they should help me get it fixed by posting duplicates, if they're interested.

I couldn't find this process detailed anywhere - just snippets of information, so I figure you guys could help me (and all other developers fresh in Cocoa / Cocoa-touch development) by detailing it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing in your control is actually #1, that is you can file bugs.  You can do this through http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ for all of Apple's products including the SDK IIRC.

Your other two points are not so easy since you can only see your bugs.  You will just have to trust that when Apple runs them through triage that thy properly flag duplicates.  Some people do include the Radar url for their bug when positing n to the mailing lists and the like. That URL only works for Apple employees, but the hope is that if you make it easy to find your bug it might get fixed sooner.

Answer (score 3):

File bugs at http://bugreport.apple.com/. After you have filed a bug at bugreporter, it helps to post it to http://openradar.me/ (not operated by Apple). It's also very useful to search against for duplicates to file against bugreporter. Not everyone uses openradar so it's not comprehensive.

Comment: I did not know about http://openradar.me/  That will be very cool if it gets more popular.

Comment: Yes, I've came across openradar.me too but had no idea how to use it. Props for reminding that!