# Getting "Directions Not Available" calling Google Maps with URLWithString 

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-location

I have an app that uses Apple Maps quite successfully: I have a list with some points of interest and if I tap one of those first the application shows it on the map, then, if I tap it, it opens Apple Maps Application to navigate.

The problem is that at the very first tap/start the app opens Apple Maps but neither if it asks the permission to use user's location nor if it doesn't, Apple Maps doesn't work and returns : "Directions Not Available. Direction could not be found between these location." but in General Setting the location service for my app is set as ON.

I thought I had to use a kind of timeout because my app takes too long to parse data for navigation (I retrieve data from an xml) but at the second tap everything works fine, even if I run it from the Mac in debugging mode (and it parses xml even the second time)...

I hope I explained well.  Any hints?

```
   -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 


    UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
    [myAccessoryButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myAccessoryButton;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    [myAccessoryButton release];
} 
else {
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"You're here"];
}
return pinView;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self; 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];

// Configure the new event with information from the location
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude]; 
NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];


CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { [latitude floatValue], [longitude floatValue] };
CLLocationCoordinate2D end = {[posto.latitude floatValue], [posto.longitude floatValue]};

NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", start.latitude, start.longitude, end.latitude, end.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, you are using `[locationManager location]` immediately after calling `startUpdatingLocation`.

The `location` is usually not available right after starting to look for the current location (and if it is, it might be unreliable or outdated).

When the `location` is available, the location manager will call its `didUpdateToLocation` delegate method and that's where you should move all the code that's after `startUpdatingLocation`.

(Even in that delegate method, it might be a good idea to check if `newLocation` is `nil` before using it.  It happens sometimes with the map view while it's waiting for the user to grant permission for location services (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680576/is-this-a-bug-with-mkmapkitdelegate-mapviewdidupdateuserlocation))).

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: newLocation is nil");
        return;
    }

    //May want to check newLocation.horizontalAccuracy and 
    //newLocation.timestamp to see if the location is accurate 
    //enough for you.  If not, return and wait for a more 
    //accurate location (which may never come).

    //all the code currently after "startUpdatingLocation" goes here...
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    ...
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"locationManager:didFailWithError: %@", error);
}
```

You may also want to implement `didFailWithError` to handle any problem obtaining the location or to at least be aware of it.

Comment: I've done the correction you told me but now the app, that asks properly the permission to use user's location, enters a kind of loop: it moves from map to app entering always  in didUpdateToLocation methods: did I forget to manage something?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention: Before calling openURL, do `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` otherwise, when it comes back to your app, it updates the location again and keeps going back to Maps app.